# Permutation of low circuit complexity

Tags: permutations, algebraic-complexity, communication-complexity

Let $\mathcal P$ be the set of permutations in $F_2^n$. I am interested in the circuit complexity of such functions in $AC^k[2]$  setup. What are the relevant upper and lower bounds in this context?

We know the class of permutations, which can be represented as a relabelling of input bits, is in $AC^0[2]$. I am interested in identifying the other classes of permutations,  which are realisable in $AC^1[2]$?

Any pointer to suitable references will also suffice?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Err, just draw the wires and you get permutations of input bits even $\mathrm{NC}^0$? Maybe I misunderstand something.

Comment: Affine permutations are $\mathrm{AC}^0[2]$. More generally, this holds for all permutations given by constant-degree polynomials.

Comment: @VilleSalo Yes, just as the OP says, permutations of input bits are an example of permutations of very low complexity. So what’s the problem with that?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: The problem is only in my reading: I read it as asking whether this is an example. I have no idea how, I read it several times before the comment.

Comment: Already NC$^0$ permutations are quite interesting, they can be P-complete to invert https://www.csc.kth.se/~johanh/onewaync0.pdf .

Comment: @all, edited my original question.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek "More generally, this holds for all permutations given by constant-degree polynomials"-- any pointer on this?

Comment: Just express each polynomial as a sum of monomials. The outer sum is a parity gate,  the monomials are an AND-gate each, and since the degree is constant, the number of monomials is only polynomial. (So I don't really need the polynomials to have constant degree; the only relevant property is that the polynomials have only polynomially many monomials.)

Comment: May be I am being naive here. How would represent a permutation in the way, you described above? Are you considering each of the $n$ co-ordinates of the output as a Boolean function $F_2^n \mapsto F_2$? Then my next question is given a set of $n$   Boolean functions, what is the necessary condition for them to collectively represent a permutation

Comment: @EmilJeřábek can you please explain how to implement efficiently affine permutations

Comment: Each coordinate of an affine function has the form $\sum_ia_ix_i+c$ for some $a_i,c\in\mathbb F_2$, that is, $\sum_{i\in I}x_i+c$ for $I=\{i:a_i=1\}$. That’s a single parity gate.